# Unable to change directories while building docker Image using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create an Image from the Dockerfile.

```
# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY $pwd/intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar /root/
COPY $pwd/login.exp /root/
RUN cd /root
RUN echo $PWD
RUN tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar 
RUN cd virtualgatewayconsole_package
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install expect \
                      expect-dev
```

**While building the Image the directory is not getting changed to /root/**. I thought the issue could be the tar file is missing, in order to confirm that printing the current working directory after the changing it to /root directory.But I have verified in the container that the packages were successfully copied to the /root directory. I have even verified by experimenting with other directories as well, even for those the directory is not getting changed.
Due to this issue the consequent steps are failing:

```
# docker build -t release:1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  633.2MB
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 6a2f32de169d
Step 2/8 : COPY $pwd/intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36e9ea407082
Step 3/8 : COPY $pwd/login.exp /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 578f9f9481d9
Step 4/8 : RUN cd /root
 ---> Running in 07ccfc507888
 ---> ad60f9d31c7e
Removing intermediate container 07ccfc507888
Step 5/8 : RUN echo $PWD
 ---> Running in e0ec2df6a0dc
/
 ---> 979a42368814
Removing intermediate container e0ec2df6a0dc
Step 6/8 : RUN tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar
 ---> Running in 0701db595e27
tar: intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

But able to change the directory within the container.

```
# docker run -it 979a42368814 /bin/bash
root@100b02ddc98a:/# pwd
/
root@100b02ddc98a:/# cd /root/
root@100b02ddc98a:~# pwd
/root
```

Please help to find out what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use WORKDIR

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

or do all in one RUN

your `cd` is "forgotten" when you are in another RUN

By the way, group your RUN, as indicated in the Dockerfile best practices

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use WORKDIR not cd in a RUN.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

> `WORKDIR /path/to/workdir` The WORKDIR instruction sets the working
>   directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that
>   follow it in the Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be
>   created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile
>   instruction.
>
> It can be used multiple times in the one Dockerfile. If a relative
>   path is provided, it will be relative to the path of the previous
>   WORKDIR instruction. For example:
>
> WORKDIR /a WORKDIR b WORKDIR c RUN pwd The output of the final pwd
>   command in this Dockerfile would be /a/b/c.
>
> The WORKDIR instruction can resolve environment variables previously
>   set using ENV. You can only use environment variables explicitly set
>   in the Dockerfile. For example:
>
> ENV DIRPATH /path WORKDIR $DIRPATH/$DIRNAME RUN pwd The output of the
>   final pwd command in this Dockerfile would be /path/$DIRNAME

```
# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY $pwd/intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar /root/
COPY $pwd/login.exp /root/
WORKDIR /root
RUN echo $PWD
RUN tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar 
WORKDIR virtualgatewayconsole_package
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install expect \
                  expect-dev
```

Regarding grouping RUN commands:
You want to logically group commands into whatever you think of as a layer. Something that could be a template for other images. If you think of this as a single layer, then just concatenating all your run commands with &&s. Also, the final WORKDIR will be the current working directory of the docker image, so keep that in mind.

```
# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY $pwd/intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar /root/
COPY $pwd/login.exp /root/
RUN cd /root && \
    echo $PWD && \
    tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar && \
    cd virtualgatewayconsole_package && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install expect \
        expect-dev
WORKDIR /root/virtualgatewayconsole_package
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `RUN cd /root` with `WORKDIR /root` and `RUN cd virtualgatewayconsole_package` with `WORKDIR virtualgatewayconsole_package`

or use

```
RUN cd /root && echo $PWD && tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar && cd virtualgatewayconsole_package && apt-get update && apt-get install expect \
                      expect-dev
```

Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments)