# Command from within Docker image doesn't work in Dockerfile RUN statement

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gradlew, cd, github-codespaces

EDIT to provide MRE:

Steps to reproduce (using Docker CLI, now, for reproducibility)

```
project_directory
   Dockerfile
   directory_to_cd_into
      gradlew
```

Dockerfile:

```
From debian:9

RUN cd /directory_to_cd_into
# also tried RUN cd ./directory_to_cd_into
```

Running `docker build` yields `/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /directory_to_cd_into`

So the problem is `cd` -- which means I must be missing something really basic about container directory structure.

Also tried `WORKDIR`

Happy to add more info.

---

Original:

From within my container, I can successfully build using gralde as follows:

`cd directory/with/gradlew && chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew build`

But when I put this in my Dockerfile and try to build the container, it fails with "file or directory gradlew does not exist":

`RUN cd directory/with/gradlew && chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew build`.

From this question, [Unable to change directories while building docker Image using Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518761/unable-to-change-directories-while-building-docker-image-using-dockerfile) , I am aware that `cd` resets with every `RUN` statement -- but I'm doing this all from within a single `RUN`.

Everything prior to this `RUN` statement is held constant, i.e., if I comment out the RUN, and build interactively from the command line in the image, it builds fine.

If it matters, I'm doing all this from within a GitHub codespace; I'm not using the Docker CLI directly.

What am I doing wrong?

--

**EDIT:**  I must be trying to include/`cd` directories from outside the build context.  I'm not sure how to fix that yet -- maybe with `COPY`?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  When you run the container, are you using something like a bind-mount of a host source tree, where the runtime contents of the container are potentially different from what's in the image build?

Comment: @DavidMaze done -- it's the `cd` that's erroring, so clearly there's something fundamental I'm not understanding about `cd`ing from *within* the container, which works, vs. from the Dockerfile, which doesn't.

Comment: The Dockerfile you included doesn't `COPY` anything into the image, so there's nothing there to `cd` into.  (`WORKDIR` will create the directory if it doesn't exist.)